# Looping over variables with wildcards in local macros

Tags: loops, stata, stata-macros

Suppose I have a dataset of variables with the following names (note the stub of `x` and `hm`):

```
x9, xdog, x_99, hma8j, hm40, hm0
```

I want to develop a programmatic way to provide a list of variable names (which may contain wildcards) and then loop through each variable name to `recode` all values less than 0 with a missing value (`.`).

In practice I have many columns and only want to `recode` some of them. I do not want to use column index or ranges because I do not know them, since my data are large.

My approach involves the following steps:

1. Create a local macro named `myvars` containing the variable names with wildcards

   ```
   local myvars x* hm*
   ```
2. Expand the strings in the variable list to contain the full variable name strings (this should produce the original variable names):

   ```
   syntax 'myvars'
   ```
3. Loop through list of variable names to set values to missing:

   ```
   foreach x of local 'myvars' { 
       replace 'x' = . if 'x' < 0
   }
   ```

However, I can't figure out how to include the wildcards in the `for` loop.
The above code does not work and produces `invalid syntax` errors.

I found the following threads on Statalist useful, but they do not provide a solution and the use of stubs does not seem efficient:

- [Selecting stubnames for -reshape- / macrolists](http://www.stata.com/statalist/archive/2008-06/msg01060.html)
- [Using foreach to loop over macros](http://www.stata.com/statalist/archive/2006-08/msg00616.html)

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
foreach x of varlist x* h* {
   replace `x'= . if `x' < 0
}
```

from here:

http://www.cpc.unc.edu/research/tools/data_analysis/statatutorial/labor_saving/loops

Answer (score 2):

@timat's answer gives a good basic solution, but does not explain what you are doing wrong.

It appears that you are getting confused on several levels:

**How to reference local macros**

Use left and right single quotes, not repeated (right) single quotes:

```
. local foo = 42

. di `foo'
42
```

**How best to unpack a wildcard variable list**

`syntax` will do this, but as `foreach` will do it directly, `syntax` is redundant for your problem. But even then your `syntax` example is quite wrong in several ways. As its use is unnecessary, I won't expand on that.

**The difference between a macro name and its contents**

```
foreach x of local `myvars' {
```

(note the corrected punctuation) is almost never what you need. It will usually be

```
foreach x of local myvars {
```

**Column thinking**

Stata is not a spreadsheet program. Columns can be your private word, and no harm done,  but column indexes are not supported directly.

**How to find answers**

You are (I guess) Googling for answers, not trying to read the Stata documentation. There's a lot of the latter and it's hard for beginners to know where to look, but basic help on `foreach` and associated explanations are more valid than the posts you cite. They are both good (it turns out I wrote both...) but some distance from your problem and it's hardly surprising that you did not find an answer to your question in either. If you want to master basic Stata, there's no real substitute for reading at least the first half of the User's Guide.

Comment: The reference to local macros issue is actually addressed in my code but I was not sure how to use correct quotes in SO since in-line code is declared using ` `. 

I am trying to understand how to do this with syntax for readability. I would prefer to use a local macro to move the variables to their own line, out of the loop code. Simply declaring the wildcards before the left-bracket of the loop makes it difficult to read. I know sequences of vars are called ranges in Stata, but that can also refer to the values of the vars.

Comment: I (we) can only go on what I (we) read here and can have no idea of what is different and correct on your computer. Agreed: The mark-up here means that you need to escape literal backticks, or, as in my answer, just give code indented. I don't think you do understand macros completely as the quotes in your `foreach ... local \`myvars'` are quite wrong for what you want. Otherwise this comment is a declaration of taste, and I doubt that any experienced Stata programmer shares your taste. There is no sense in which `syntax` would do anything except give you a very indirect solution here.